# Get text-file word occurrence count of all words & print output sorted

Tags: sort

I had a command which would work through a text file, count all the occurrences of the words and print it out like this:

```
user@box $˜ magic-command-i-forgot | with grep | and awk | sort ./textfile.txt
66: the
54: and
32: I
16: unix
12: bash
5:  internet
3:  sh
1: GNU/Linux
```

So it does not search line-by-line, but word by word, and it does it for all the words, not just for 1 word. I'd found it somewhere on the internets a long time ago, but I cannot find or remember it..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would use `tr` instead of *awk*:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit sit amet et cetera." | tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr
```

- `tr` just replaces spaces with newlines
- `grep -v "^\s*$"` trims out empty lines
- `sort` to prepare as input for `uniq`
- `uniq -c` to count occurrences
- `sort -bnr` sorts in numeric reverse order while ignoring whitespace

wow. it turned out to be a great command to count [swear-per-lines](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/wordcount/)

> find . -name "*.py" -exec cat {} \; | tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr | grep fuck

Comment: Might want to use `tr -s` to handle multiple spaces, especially when encountering indentation.

Comment: @Arcege: Good point. Although it wont change the result it may fasten script a little bit.

Comment: `-g` (`--general-numeric-sort`) option of `sort` may be preferable in some cases.  E.g. `sort -n` will keep `10\n1 4` as is, treating `1 4` as `14`, while `sort -g` will treat it correctly as `1 4\n10`.

Comment: nice command, really deserve a vote up :)

Comment: @seler I think you can make the grep and tr part even simpler like below: `echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit sit amet et cetera." | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v "^$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr` Note that I am a beginner, so I may be wrong, please feel free to advise.

Answer (score 9):

1. Split the input into words, one per line.
2. Sort the resulting list of words (lines).
3. Squash multiple occurences.
4. Sort by occurrence count.

To split the input into words, replace any character that you deem to be a word separator by a newline.

```
<input_file \
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' | # Add digits, -, ', ... if you consider
                             # them word constituents
sort |
uniq -c |
sort -nr
```

Comment: This is a nice answer because it can handle the case where the words are directly next to some non-word punctuation that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 5):

Not using grep and awk but this seems to do what you want:

```
for w in `cat maxwell.txt`; do echo $w; done|sort|uniq -c
  2 a
  1 A
  1 an
  1 command
  1 considered
  1 domain-specific
  1 for
  1 interpreter,
  2 is
  1 language.
  1 line
  1 of
```

Comment: This won't work if the input contains shell wildcards (you need to add `set -f`), and treats punctuation as part of words (which can be fixed awkwardly by adding punctuation characters to `IFS` — good luck trying to support non-ASCII character sets). This won't be good with very large input files, as it stores the whole file in memory (`sort` is smarter).

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk/sort/uniq` solution:

```
awk '{for(w=1;w<=NF;w++) print $w}' ~/textFile.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're after something like this?

```
$ perl -n -e 'foreach ${k} (split(/\s+/)){++$h{$k}};END{foreach $l (keys(%h)){print "$h{$l}: ${l}\n"}}' /path/to/your/file | sort -n -k 1
```

of course you can do the same with `awk` as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file=/home/stefan/ooxml1.txt
for word in $(sed 's/[^A-Za-z]/ /g' $file | tr " " "\n" | sort -u)
do
  echo -n "$word "
  grep -c $word $file
done | sort -k2 -n
```

sorts ascending after splitting the file into words.

The simple grep will find `fish` in `fisheye`, so you have to enhance the grep command to prevent partial matches.

Takes about 3s for a 25k text file on a machine in the ages, classical HDD (IDE).

For bigger files or often performed operations a hash map approach would be better, but for a seldom run job or smaller files only, it might be sufficient.