# How to make a list and count LaTeX keywords in a source file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, latex

I am trying to make  lists (and eventually count and make statistics) the  LaTeX keywords appearing in some documents.
Basically a LaTeX "valid" keyword can be identified by:

1. The fact that it does not begin with a "%" sign (it would be commented therefore not in use)
2. It starts with a backslash.
3. Is is followed by either a left curly bracket (or a left bracket, in case there are options.)

I understand there are other "special" cases: keywords followed by nothing (a white space), or  another keyword, but these are relatively rare and I do no mind the inaccuracy. My primary goal is to get eventually a rought idea of the number of different keywords in various types of documents.

I have tried various ways using awk, but could not get anything working...
I have attached a MWE (meaningless and not functional!) of a LaTeX file for reference.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt} % Mode production
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\fancypagestyle{FrontPageTestReportStyle}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\newcommand{\WaterMark}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[rotate=60]
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.46\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#2]{#3}\caption {#4}
\end{minipage}
\caption {#3}
\end{figure}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{|c|cS|cS|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Part number}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cavity A}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cavity B}\\
\end {tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that splits out the LaTeX commands in a source file. It strips comments beginning with `%`. It outputs all the commands with a leading `\`, and all the environment names as well.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\(\)*\)%.*/\1/' \
    -e 's/\([^\\]\(\\\\\)*\)%.*/\1/' \
    -e 's/\\./\n&/g' |
sed -n -e 's/^\\begin *{\([^{}]*\)}.*/\1/p' \
       -e 's/^\\end *{.*//' \
       -e 's/^\(\\[@A-Za-z][@A-Za-z]*\).*/\1/p' \
       -e 's/^\(\\[^@A-Za-z]\)/\1/p' |
```

Explanations:

1. The first `sed` pass adds a newline before every backslash. The first two expressions strip off comments, taking care to retain `\%` but still strip comments that are preceded by `\\`.
2. In the second `sed` pass, the first expression prints environment names from `\begin` commands and the second expression ignores `\end` commands. The third expression prints commands whose names are letters and the fourth expression prints commands whose name is a symbol.

This script does not handle verbatim environments.

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile, I have seen in a LaTeX course a reference to  a utility called "texcount" [link] (http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) It seems to do the type of job I had in mind, while obviously far more ambitious...

Comment: After additional investigations, texcount eliminates from the count the works I am interested in. As it does not seem practical to operate a substraction, I am going to go the sed way.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a variation on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/get-text-file-word-occurrence-count-of-all-words-print-output-sorted/39041#39041).

So I'll work on that answer:

```
for w in `cat test.tex`; do echo $w; done|sort|egrep '\\[a-z]*{'|uniq -c
  1 A}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cavity
  1 \begin{figure}[H]
  1 \begin{minipage}[b]{.46\textwidth}
  1 \begin{tabular}{|c|cS|cS|}
  1 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember
```

The regular expression may need some work but this should get you started.

Comment: This isn't going to work well. You can see that `\multicolumn` isn't split off. The shell's globbing is going to fire up (try with a file containing `$a * b$`), you need to run `set -f` first.

Comment: The nice part in this solution is the integrated counter.