# Counting the instances of specific words in a text, using awk

Tags: awk, grep

If I have a file `words_of_interest.txt` with one word per line, is there a way to use `awk` (or some other *nix tools) to obtain the number of times each of these words occurs in another text file `my_text.txt`, using only one pass?

Currently I am `grep -c`'ing  the text for each word, but this is quite slow because the text is large, and there are several hundred words to search for.

EDIT: providing sample input and output:

```
[words_of_interest.txt]
joe
hi

[my_text.txt]
hi joe
hi jack
nice day today

[output]
joe 1
hi 2
```

EDIT2: To those who marked this question as duplicate: the [question you point to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/get-text-file-word-occurrence-count-of-all-words-print-output-sorted) is about counting *all* the words, whereas this one is about counting only the instances of a specific pre-defined set of words.

Comment: Please provide sample input/output

Comment: May be this helps: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_204.html

Comment: @Ketan indeed that is helpful for a start, but it would need to be adapted to count only the specific words in `words_of_interest.txt`

Comment: @muru do you agree with my EDIT2?

Comment: @jofel do you agree with my EDIT2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplistic scenarios involving fixed string search and space-separated words in `my_text.txt`, GNU `awk` might work, although output order may not match that of `words_of_interest.txt`

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]; next}; $0 in a{b[$0]++}; 
    END{for (k in b) print k, b[k]}' words_of_interest.txt RS='[[:space:]]+' my_text.txt
hi 2
joe 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't output anything on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Oddly, it works now that I installed the `gawk` package (although I use the `awk` command)

Comment: @mitchus, great. Yes, Ubuntu has `mawk` by default. `RS='[[:space:]]+'` is GNU awk-specific